# Multiplicity constraint violated SQL Server 2008 - CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, code-first

I'm working to solve a very tedious problem.
I have a class called Nation and a class called NationAlly

```
public class Nation   
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int name {get;set;}
    public List<NationAlly> NationAllies {get;set;}
}

public class NationAlly
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int level {get;set;}
    public Nation toNation {get;set;}
}
```

I'm using EF 4 and CodeFirst with a DbContext called NationsDB to manage my database on SQL Server 2008.
If I create a new object of type Nation and I try to call nationsDB.SaveChanges, I got the following exception:

"Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'NationAlly_toNation_Target' of the relationship 'CodeFirstNamespace.NationAlly_toNation' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1."

I tried to save a Nation with NationAllies field null and this exception is not thrown, the nation table in the database gets all the correct values.

In my database the table Nation has 2 fields: ID(primary key), name
The table NationAlly has 3 fields: ID(primary key), level, NationID
The two tables are linked with a relationship where NationAlly.NationID is foreign key and Nation.ID is primary key.

Isn't strange? In my eyes the table NationAlly should have a field called NationID1 and another called NationID2 to create the "relationship" between a nation and a list of other nations.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is `NationAlly` supposed to represent a many-to-many relationship? i.e., A nation has many allies, and can also be an ally to many nations?

Comment: A Nation as of course many NationAllies, since in nation there is a list of NationAlly entities. A single NationAlly entity has one and only one Nation which is the "Owner" nation (the one who has the list of NationAlly) and one and only one Nation which is the "toNation" to which the relationship is adressing.

Comment: When exactly do you get the exception? You write that you "create a new object of type Nation", call SaveChanges and the exception is thrown. Two paragraphs below you write: "I tried to save a Nation with NationAllies field null and this exception is not thrown." Where is the difference? Do you add NationAllies in the first case?

Comment: The exception is thrown when I call SaveChanges. In the other paragraph I was just describing that no exception at all is thrown if I leave the field NationAllies null.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are perhaps a victim of the EF Code-First mapping conventions which create automatically a relationship between `NationAllies` and `toNation` you don't want to have.

If I understand you correctly (but I am not 100 percent sure, if I do), you actually want to have two relationships and you have exposed only one end of the relationship in each of the entities. So, `NationAllies` does NOT point to `toNation` but to an "invisible" Owner nation in your `NationAlly` entity.

If that is the case you need to explicitly overwrite the convention mappings. In the Fluent API of EF 4.1 this could look like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Nation> Nations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NationAlly> NationAllies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Nation>()
            .HasMany(n => n.NationAllies)
            .WithRequired()
            .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("OwnerID"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<NationAlly>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.toNation)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("NationID"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

This mapping would create the two foreign keys `OwnerID` and `NationID` in the `NationAllies` table, both pointing to the primary key `ID` in the `Nations` table.

**Edit**

Here is the application I have tested with:

- Create a new Console App in VS2010 / .NET 4.0, name it "NationsApp"
- Add a reference to "EntityFramework.dll"
- Clear the content of "Program.cs" and paste instead the following in:

Content of Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace NationsApp
{
    public class Nation
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int name { get; set; }
        public List<NationAlly> NationAllies { get; set; }
    }

    public class NationAlly
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int level { get; set; }
        public Nation toNation { get; set; }
    }

    public class NationsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Nation> Nations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NationAlly> NationAllies { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Nation>()
                .HasMany(n => n.NationAllies)
                .WithRequired()
                .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("OwnerID"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<NationAlly>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.toNation)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("NationID"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new NationsContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    // We have three Nations and two Allies
                    Nation nation1 = new Nation() {
                        NationAllies = new List<NationAlly>() };
                    Nation nation2 = new Nation() {
                        NationAllies = new List<NationAlly>() };
                    Nation nation3 = new Nation() {
                        NationAllies = new List<NationAlly>() };
                    NationAlly ally1 = new NationAlly();
                    NationAlly ally2 = new NationAlly();

                    // Nation1 has two Allies
                    // (Nation1 is the "owner" of both Allies)
                    nation1.NationAllies.Add(ally1);
                    nation1.NationAllies.Add(ally2);

                    // toNation of ally1 refers to Nation2
                    ally1.toNation = nation2;
                    // toNation of ally2 refers to Nation3
                    ally2.toNation = nation3;

                    context.Nations.Add(nation1);
                    context.Nations.Add(nation2);
                    context.Nations.Add(nation3);

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can set a breakpoint on "throw" to watch possible exceptions in e in the debugger.

This creates a database called `NationsApp.NationsContext` if you are using SQL Server Express and don't have any further connection strings defined.

It gives two relationships `Nation_NationAllies` (FK is "OwnerID") and `NationAlly_toNation` (FK is "NationID"). All columns are non-nullable. The result in the DB is the following:

[image: Nations and NationAllies]

Comment: I think you really understood my problem, thanks. I'm trying your suggestion right now. But VS2010 doesn't let me add a DbModelBuilder (is marked as unknown) even if I have a reference to System.Data.Entity. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Francesco: Which version of EF Code-First are you using? There exists a CTP4 version (Summer 2010), CTP5 from December 2010 and the last one is called EF 4.1 (Release Candidate) from this month (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx , there is also the download link in this post). My code is based on this last version. You should upgrade in any case, nobody is going to help you with the old preliminary versions sooner or later.

Comment: And you also need a reference to `EntityFramework.dll`, not only System.Data.Entity.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, I had the older version

Comment: @Slauma: Even with this approach the code-first engine is generating 3 relationships instead of 2.

Comment: @Francesco: Do you have anything else in `OnModelCreating` or only the code in my answer? Do you have attributes on your model classes? Are the two classes `Nation` and `NationAlly` exactly as you have shown at the beginning of your question? Or are there additional navigation properties? I'm asking so pedantic because I have reproduced the example with those two classes and the model builder code in my answer - and I get only 2 relationships as I had described. Something important must be different or missing... Can you check the details?

Comment: @Francesco: I've added a complete test app example you can copy and paste. You can build it and compare with what you have.

Comment: @Slauma: Thanks for all the support. Great!

Answer (score 6):

In case this helps someone getting this error... I was getting this message while doing queries rather than saving to the database. My data design:

```
public class Base {
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Child {
    [Key][ForeignKey("Base")] public int Id {get; set;}

    public virtual Base Base {get; set;}

    public Child() {
        Base = new Base();
    }
}
```

The problem was in the constructor. Turns out EF4.1 doesn't like when you initialize associations there! I removed that constructor and things started working again.