# updating a record throws 'Multiplicity constraint violated.' in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am developing an application in asp.net mvc and using EF code first for my data access. Here is the model I use :

```
  public class Culture
    {
        [Key()]
        public int CultureID { get; set; }

        [Required()]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string CultureName { get; set; }

        [Required()]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string CultureDisplay { get; set; }

        public virtual List<HomePage> HomePage { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Person_Local> PersonLocal { get; set; }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string PersonPicAddress { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Person_Local> PersonLocal { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person_Local
    {
        //[NotMapped()]
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        [ForeignKey("Culture")]
        public int CultureID { get; set; }

        public string PersonName { get; set; }

        public string PersonFamily { get; set; }

        public string PersonAbout { get; set; }

        public virtual Culture Culture { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
```

I dont have any problem adding new person and personlocal to db. But when I want to update the person local, as below:

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson([Bind(Prefix = "Person")]Person obj,
            [Bind(Prefix = "Person.PersonLocal")]IEnumerable<Person_Local> plocals)
        {
            string photo_guid = obj.PersonPicAddress;

            if (obj.PersonID != 0)
            {
                Person p = da.Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonID == obj.PersonID);

                TryUpdateModel(p, "Person");

                if (obj.PersonLocal[0].Person.PersonID != 0)
                {
                    int cid = obj.PersonLocal[0].Culture.CultureID;
                    int pid = obj.PersonLocal[0].Person.PersonID;

                    Person_Local ploc = 
                                      da.Person_Locals.First(x => x.CultureID == cid      && x.PersonID == pid);



                   //update ploc 


                 }

                 da.SaveChanges();
          }
}
```

I got following error :

Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Person_Local_Person_Target' of the relationship 'WebApp.Models.Person_Local_Person' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

Edited:

I commented

```
TryUpdateModel(p, "Person");
```

And the it seems the problem has been solved ?!! Why ?!

Comment: It seem you have the multiplicity badly mapped. Check your edmx just to confirm. I'm curious, do you need both your relationship and the FK in the object? It's not enough with the relationship?

Comment: @ivowiblo, Check edmx  for what ?  Yes I need both of them, cause when the client wants to enter a new person local, he/she should identify the culture and the person. Client can identify a person, and have multilingual detail of person, and it is possible by using person_local

Comment: I mean, if it's needed the Person relationship and the PersonID FK in your object. I thought EF handles the FK internally. Maybe you are not using EF 4.

Comment: You mean I should remove PersonID and CultureId from PersonLocal ? I am using EF Version 4.1.0.0. When I remove them from personlocal and run application it throws  : EntityType 'Person_Local' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Comment: It seems you checked "include foreign keys in the model". It shouldn't be the problem anyway. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422947/multiplicity-constraint-violated-sql-server-2008-codefirst

Comment: I edited my question. I am using cod first approach, where can I check or unccheck 'include foreign keys in the model' ?

Comment: Nevermind that. Check the link I passed, it seems the same problem. you'll need to override some mappings in order to make EF understand your model (it's common)

Comment: I already read that, is owner id column necessary ?

Comment: In the link you provided, there is 'ownerid' defined in 'Nation' entity configuration.

Comment: oh, ok. I think you already have it